# Stream audio to multiple bluetooth headsets from a single bluetooth device?

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, bluez

I want to stream an identical audio (music) stream from one linux box to two bluetooth headsets, as follows:

[image]

According to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693033/ios-playing-audio-to-multiple-bluetooth-devices-concurrently) there's not enough bandwidth in a single bluetooth device to send two audio streams.

Does that mean the only way to accomplish the above is to have multiple bluetooth devices on the linux box?