# Programmatically Create Aggregate Audio Devices In Swift Using CoreAudio

Tags: swift, xcode, aggregate, core-audio

I am researching creating multi-output devices on either OS X or iOS, and [I found out that CoreAudio would allow you to create aggregate devices.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH6-SW14)  My first question is, does iOS allow you to do this. I know that this is certainly possible on OS X, but I've heard that iOS will not allow it. I would really appreciate an example of how you would go about detecting multiple audio output devices and creating an aggregate device, all using swift.  I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469569/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-multi-output-device-in-os-x), but it doesn't fully answer my question, and the answer it does have is based on Objective-C.  I'd appreciate any help, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate audio device API is not publicly available on iOS, so you cannot create those devices yourself.

**However** iOS will create aggregate devices<sup>*</sup> for you depending on the most recently attached audio hardware and some other rules *if* you activate an `AVAudioSession` that uses the `.multiRoute` category.

When you get a route change notification due to an audio interface being added or removed, you can create a remote IO audio unit with the right number of channels. I haven’t tried using multi route audio with `AVAudioEngine` nor have I tried using only a subset of the available channels.

<sup>*</sup> They’re probably aggregate devices, although you never see them or interact with them directly.

Comment: But unfortunately it appears that the multiRoute category does not support bluetooth audio devices? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616518-allowbluetooth (Seriously, come on Apple)

Comment: oh that really sucks, they work fine on osx aggregate audio devices  (apart from the whole aggregate incurring that bluetooth latency)